# How to proxy web requests to Lucee/Tomcat under Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, lucee

I'm having trouble setting Lucce to run on Apache in a CentOS 9 machine.
The steps I've followed are bellow:

- Installed .run file from https://downloads.lucee.org
- Left the default for apachectl, httpd conf and http modules (I've already checked and it seems they're correct, I can provide the values if you need)
- Set Tomcat to run on port 8888, the default value (tomcat is in fact running because i can access it externally)
- Accepted to install Apache connector
- Accepted to install mod_cfml

Then, when Lucee is being installed, I get a post-install step error, mentioning that the installation may not complete correctly:

```
Error running /opt/lucee/sys/install_mod_proxy.sh -m install -t 8888 -f
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -c /usr/sbin/apachectl: apachectl: The "-M" option is
not supported.
apachectl: The "-M" option is not supported.
```

But the installation process ends and everything seems to be fine.

- Tomcat is running (I can access through domain.com:8888)
- Proxy is added to `httpd.conf` file with the following rules

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        # optional mappings
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
</IfModule>
```

- mod_cfml is loaded in `httpd.conf` file

```
LoadModule modcfml_module modules/mod_cfml.so
CFMLHandlers ".cfm .cfc .cfml"
ModCFML_SharedKey "{{ shared_key_here }}"
LogHeaders false
LogHandlers false
LogAliases false
VDirHeader false
```

In the end I restarted Lucee and Apache services and created a index.cfm file in `/var/www/html`, but when I try o access it I get a 503 error.

`The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

Catalina.out logs from tomcat and error_logs from apache dont give me any hints on whats happerning.

Can anyone point me any direction to solve this?

Any additional info you may need in order to help me fell free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: The installer might have failed to install/activate mod_proxy to your apache2. Looks like the option -M fails on Centos because the command for listing the modules  is likely to be different on Centos ("httpd -M" instead of "apachectl -M" which could be the cause of the issue).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, the installer indeed activated/installed mod_proxy and mod_cfml, I found that the machine has SELinux enabled and there is a setting that was preventing the request to be proxied correctly to tomcat `httpd_can_network_connect=false`, i had to change it to `httpd_can_network_connect=true`. But thanks @AndreasRu

Answer (score 2):

So I found that my machine had SE (Security Enhanced) enabled, and there was a setting that prevented the request to be correctly proxied to tomcat, which is `httpd_can_network_connect`.

I had to run `/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect true` in order to make it work, after this and restarting httpd service, everything was ok!